# Is it possible to make a custom css for "each" primefaces themes?

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

My application has a primefaces theme switcher and in total are five themes (e.g. aristo or home) available to select.

Now I need to change the appearance of a text in a menu with css. This appearance should look in every theme different (e.g. in aristo the hoover of a link should be white, but in the theme aristo it should be black).

Currently I load all primefaces with the pom.xml and I like to keep it that way.

```
        <!-- Primefaces -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>5.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Primefaces Themes -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
            <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.10</version>
        </dependency>
```

The theme will be read in the web.xml:

```
<!-- PrimeFaces Theme Definition -->
<context-param>
  <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
  <param-value>#{clubCustomizedController.theme}</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I dont need a custom theme, because I need to make differente css fittings for each theme.
How can I make a customized css 'for EACH theme?

Answer (score 0):

You may simply create your custom Primefaces theme using Themeroller or 3rd party app. Look [here](http://www.primefaces.org/themes) (look at the bottom) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

The following css tag worked for me:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/resources/css/#{clubCustomizedController.theme}.css" />
```